# Dynamic Input error within tables or divs

Tags: php, jquery, html

Can somebody please explain why this code does not allow my imploded variable separated by commas does not work when I surround it in a table or many div format.

The code works when I remove it from within the table. I also tested it with elements of the form within other divs and that failed to. It only works when its a HTML form on its own.

**Summary: I want engineers output like. john,derek,peter et al.... At the moment it only gives my the top line**

```
<?php
$eng = array();
$test = $_POST['test'];
$eng = implode(',',$_POST['engineers']);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>    
   $(document).ready(function(){
        //when the Add Filed button is clicked
        $("#add").click(function (e) {
            //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
            $("#items").append('<div><input type="text" name="engineers[]"><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');
        });
        $("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
            $(this).parent("div").remove();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $eng; ?>
<div class="form_table">
<table>
<form method="post">        
    <tr><th><label for="engineers">Engineers</label></th><td>    
    <button type="button" id="add">Add Another Engineer</button>
    <div id="items">
        <div><input type="text" name="engineers[]"></div>
    </div>    
    </td></tr>        
    <tr><th colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="" value="Add Job"  class="submit" /></th></tr>        
</form></table>             
</body>         
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to point out is that always process form input when the form is **submitted**.

And your markup is a little bit wrong, its the other way around. The table must be inside the form.

```
<?php
// handle form inputs when the form is submitted
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $eng = implode(',', array_filter($_POST['engineers']));
    echo $eng;
}

?>

<div class="form_table">
<!-- form must wrap the table -->
    <form method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><label for="engineers">Engineers</label></th>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" id="add">Add Another Engineer</button>
                    <div id="items">
                        <div><input type="text" name="engineers[]" /></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" name="" value="Add Job" class="submit" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //when the Add Filed button is clicked
    $("#add").click(function (e) {
        //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
        $("#items").append('<div><input type="text" name="engineers[]"> <button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');
    });

    $("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
        $(this).parent("div").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eTVEn2)

Comment: I have the `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` in my actual project, just not for testing. Thanks for the form information, that seems to solve half the issue. Is there any reason why having multiple DIVs to separate the forms on the page would effect anything?

Comment: @OliverB oh okay, i thought you don't have one since its not included in the question. no that should not obstruct anything. as long as the inputs are wrapped inside the form it should be fine.

Comment: @OliverB by the way, what do you mean solves half the issue? what seems to be not working? i've setup a demo below the answer, you can kindly check that

Comment: sorry @Ghost, im trying to confuse the issue! You did solve my issue, i just ammended my page and finally its working, its always the stupidest things. basic format failure. thanks again

Comment: @OliverB oh okay, yes that subtle thing can just mess up your day if you're caught off guard. anyways, im glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

put your form outside the table becase table tag can include tr tags not form tag

Ex:

```
 <?php


        $eng = array();

    $test = $_POST['test'];

    $eng = implode(',',$_POST['engineers']);
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>

     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

            <script>    $(document).ready(function(){
            //when the Add Filed button is clicked
            $("#add").click(function (e) {
                //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
                $("#items").append('<div><input type="text" name="engineers[]">
<button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');
            });

        $("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
            $(this).parent("div").remove();
        });
        });
      </script>
        </head>
        <body><?php
    echo $eng;
    ?>

            <div class="form_table">
<form method="post">
    <table>

    <tr><th><label for="engineers">Engineers</label></th><td>


    <button type="button" id="add">Add Another Engineer</button>
        <div id="items">
            <div><input type="text" name="engineers[]"></div>
            </div>



    </td></tr>

    <tr><th colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="" value="Add Job"  class="submit" /></th></tr>

    </table>
</form>
```